# Avoiding hernia

Tags: weightlifting, hernia

Are there any precautions for avoiding hernia when performing weightlifting? When doing exercises at the preacher curl bench, it feels as if my organs are strained.

Can weightlifting belts aid in this or are they only good for your back?

**Update:**

It feels like my organs get pushed farther away from their "*rest position*" when performing the exercises stated above.

Comment: Why do you think you have a risk of getting a hernia? Because that's probably a good indication of what the answerer's should focus on ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [general causes for a hernia](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmedhealth/PMH0001956/#adam_000960.disease.causes) as relates to this question include:

- Extra weight
- Heavy lifting
- Poor nutrition
- Overexertion

While I'm not a doctor, nor do I play one on TV, I'll go out on a limb and say that the overexertion and heavy lifting required to cause a hernia are when it is above and beyond what the body is prepared to handle.  If you have gone up in weights more quickly than you are really prepared for, then you might be in danger.  Particularly if your core is not already strong enough to support what you are doing at the preacher curl bench.

Weightlifting belts are meant to provide stability in your core.  It will compress your organs even more.  It appears that the hernia is more related to the muscle tissue than the organs themselves.